# Intranet Content Management System

Tags: cms, free, intranet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am looking to find a free CMS that would be suitable for an intranet environment with around 50 users. What suggestions do you guys have?

All that is required really is a few pages listing links to different documents on the network and possibly an event calender.

Comment: This belongs on WebMaster, most likely. That said, you don't have enough information to get a usable answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a cms you can use Drupal, it's a great option, there's a LDAP module so you can use with Active Directory. Sharepoint Foundations is great too like @Phil points out, but only runs on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed [Sharepoint Foundations](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/Related-Technologies/Pages/SharePoint-Foundation.aspx) and it was easy to set up and the quite powerful. The best part about it is that it's free!

I don't know what you're using, but it connects instantly with active directory (AD) if it's on the same domain as the AD server.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki): It's opensource, flat-file (no database needed) and thus easy to backup and maintain. It has a rights management and plugins for additional features.